# How to inject http response using REST in java

Tags: java, rest, paypal, payflowpro

I have an android app that is using Payflow from PayPal to process payments. when the front-end calls PayPal, it passes a redirect_url to PayPal. The redirect_url is a RESTful service call to the back-end.
Paypal returns a response to the redirect_url. How will that work? How do I inject a Response object into a service call? Do I simply user InputStream? Could I use @headerParam? If so, how?